# Верно ли согласование с числительным?

Tags: числительные

«По последним подсчётам, популяция включает 121 взрослое животное и 14 котят».

Comment: А так правильно? С 121.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Имею в виду предлог: "с" или "со"? Устно ясно, что "со", а письменно? Вопрос ко всем, кто знает.

Comment: «Всегда употребляется предлог «со» в том случае, если следующее слово начинается на две и более согласных, первая из которых «с» или «з»».. Cто двадцать один... Со 121 животным, получается...

Comment: Ну да, это устно. Но не так давно столкнулся с тем, что с датами пишется "с", например "с 2 декабря", хотя читается "со". Непонятно, здесь так же и Вы правильно написали или с(о) 121 надо использовать "со". Давайте перейдём на "вы" с маленькой друг к другу?

Comment: Ок, давайте)... Ведь читается «со второго декабря», должно быть «со», не «с»...

Comment: Да, мне тоже это разница звучания и написания кажется странной. Так те, кто не знает, как правильно говорить, и будут произносить по написанному, как, например, с Кадашёвским переулком, который некоторые называют КадАшевским (видимо, потому что Ё редко пишут, они и не знают).

Comment: Кто живет на этом переулке, знает, как его писать, я думаю)... А «ко» и «к» вроде тоже так же...

Comment: Да, наверно, так же. Только не на переулке, а в.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Популяция включает сто двадцать одно взрослое животное, всё верно.